# I have recorded a meeting on video but audio is over level and creaking what filter should I use to fix that and get the clean audio

Tags: noise-cancelling

Want to fix the over level audio recording which is on my video recording

Comment: Why don't you post a snippet of it to see if anyone can fix it - there is no magic silver bullet. Clipping is destructive but maybe something can be restored

Comment: Relevant: http://sound.stackexchange.com/q/27211/7176

Answer (score 1):

This is damaged sound. speak to a specialist to potentially repair it, if it's not *d up beyond recognition. There is no magic button, and i don't think there will ever be. Have a look at restoration software such as iZotope [RX](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/rx2/protips.asp) if you have the time to fiddle with the controls. I'm not affiliated with iZotope.

Answer (score 1):

If the signal has clipped digitally there's no easy way to expand it and get it back to normal, but you're not very clear with your question. It sounds as if you've either clipped digitally or have a very low signal to noise ration, in which case you could try and use noise reducing software such as Isotope RX plug ins.

Otherwise next time make sure that your recorder's limiter is set on because a squashed signal is better than a broken one.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the Limiter and also try lowering the db in the master vol this should fix the problem. For clicks and pops you can try useing the eq lower down the high frequency a bit. If there is still problem with the sound there are free software to do noise isolation.

Comment: You're not answering the question posted here, did you misunderstand the question? It is about fixing clipping audio that is already recorded. Your suggestion does nothing for that.

Comment: Post the auido on here let me fix